# SQL many to many select people with multiple vacancies

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with sql server through SSMS right now. How can i choose all people  with multiple(>2)vacancies?
I am trying something like that, but i dont understand how to make part with "more than 2 vacancies"?

```
SELECT        dbo.applicants.FirstName, dbo.vacancy.Name
FROM            dbo.applicants INNER JOIN
                         dbo.VacancyApplicant ON dbo.applicants.id = dbo.VacancyApplicant.ApplicantId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.vacancy ON dbo.VacancyApplicant.VacancyId = dbo.vacancy.id WHERE dbo.vacancy.Name='third vacancy'
```

[image: DB schema]

Comment: I've removed the tag [tag:mysql]as the OP is clearly using SQL Server, *not* MySQL, due to statement that are using SSMS (**SQL Server** management Studio), the use of the `dbo` schema in their SQL, and the image is of an SSMS Database Diagram.

Comment: Side note, 3+ part naming for columns is to  be deprecated and should be avoided. Alias your objects and use those to qualify your columns.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT        dbo.applicants.FirstName, dbo.vacancy.Name
FROM            dbo.applicants A INNER JOIN
            dbo.VacancyApplicant V ON A.id = V.ApplicantId
WHERE EXIST(
SELECT        1
FROM          dbo.applicants INNER JOIN
              dbo.VacancyApplicant ON dbo.applicants.id = 
dbo.VacancyApplicant.ApplicantId INNER JOIN
          dbo.vacancy ON dbo.VacancyApplicant.VacancyId = dbo.vacancy.id 
WHERE A.id=dbo.applicants.id
GROUP BY dbo.applicants.id,dbo.vacancy.id 
HAVING COUNT(1)>2
)
```

Comment: Oh sh... At the same time :) ahhah you have my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

`Group By` and `Having` are you basic answer. Below is a simple solution, might not be ideal, but can give you the idea.
I am finding target "applicants" ids in subquery, that uses `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` then outer query joins to that to output FirstName and LastName of applicant

```
SELECT dbo.applicants.FirstName, dbo.applicants.LastName FROM
dbo.applicants a INNER JOIN
(
SELECT        dbo.applicants.id
FROM            dbo.applicants INNER JOIN
                     dbo.VacancyApplicant ON dbo.applicants.id = dbo.VacancyApplicant.ApplicantId INNER JOIN
                     dbo.vacancy ON dbo.VacancyApplicant.VacancyId = dbo.vacancy.id AND dbo.vacancy.Name='third vacancy'
GROUP BY dbo.applications.id
HAVING COUNT(dbo.vacancy.id) > 2
) targetIds ON a.id = targetIds.id
```

Answer (score 1):

> "more than 2 vacancies"?

Your question only mentions vacancies but your query is filtering for a particular name.  I assume you really want more than two of that name.

If I understand correctly, you want aggregation:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.Name
FROM dbo.applicants a INNER JOIN
     dbo.VacancyApplicant va
     ON a.id = va.ApplicantId INNER JOIN
     dbo.vacancy v
     ON va.VacancyId = v.id
WHERE v.Name = 'third vacancy'
GROUP BY a.FirstName, v.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Note the use of table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TempCTE AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT ap.FirstName
,vc.Name
,COUNT (va.VacancyId) OVER (PARTITION BY ap.id) AS NoOfVacancies
FROM dbo.applicants ap
JOIN dbo.VacancyApplicant va 
  ON ap.id = va.ApplicantId 
JOIN dbo.vacancy vc 
  ON va.VacancyId = vc.id
 )
 SELECT FirstName,[Name], NoOfVacancies FROM TempCTE 
 WHERE NoOfVacancies > 2
```

Comment: The semi-colon is a statement **terminator**, not a "beginator". Use statement terminators consistently and you will never need to put one "ahead of" a CTE. You also over-complicate your query - without explanation - by using the windowed count. That approach forces the kludge of using DISTINCT. You also added a visual error by giving the Name column an alias of "NoOfVacancies".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll take care of these in my future answers.